# ListView onItemClick only gets the first item

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to get the text of the selected item and show it in a toast message. This is the code I wrote:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.firstflightlist);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            TextView c = (TextView) arg0.findViewById(arg1.getId());

            String text = c.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
        }});
```

The listview is a single choice listview. When I click on any item in the list, it always displays the first item of the list. What might be causing this? How can I get the selected item's text?

Comment: Read what the params are for : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need to findViewById, you've got the view you clicked on.
also findViewById only finds the first item that matches the id, and in a list view you've got a lot of items with the same id, so it finds the first one

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {


        TextView c = (TextView) arg1; //<--this one 
        String text = c.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
    }});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the `arg0` which is the `AdapterView`. You should get `arg1` instead which refers to the clicked view.

```
String text = ((TextView) arg1).getText();
```

---

> **parent**    The AdapterView where the click happened.
>   **view**  The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the
>   adapter)
>   **position**  The position of the view in the adapter.
>   **id**    The row id of the item that was clicked.

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, 
                                  View view, 
                                  int position, 
                                  long id)
```

See [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String text = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
    }});
```

assuming that your ListView is filled up with String

Comment: could it not be arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(); instead of casting it to string?

Comment: Give those damn parameters some discriptive names! If Eclipse generated this code you have to add the android library code and it will generate the right parameters names for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I feel that list view having the items then, can directly use below line inside onClick() method to get selected text from the list view:

```
String text = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

This will give the selected text from the list view and can be used everywhere.