# ListView.setSelection is not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-dialog

I am working on a dialog that has a `ListView` ..

I have successfully put the adapter,selector,list_itemlayout in the `onCreate()` as follows..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.variable_dialog);

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.VariableslistView1);
    lv.setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);        
    final ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Program.get().symboltable.getSymbols());
    lv.setAdapter(ad);

    lv.setSelector(R.drawable.item_selected);
```

But whenever I try to get the `getSelectedItemPosition()` it alsways returns -1

as if I didn't select anything ..even if I invoke the selection my self like this:

```
lv.setSelected(true);
    lv.setSelection(1);
    lv.setItemChecked(1, true);
    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
    ad.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

and here is my selector :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FF00FF00" />

<gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
    android:startColor="#DD000000" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />


</shape>
```

For god's sake what the heck is wrong?!?!

I even tried the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` but never succeeded :|

Can anybody tell me what is the problem .

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010870/listview-onitemclick-only-gets-the-first-item check this might help

Comment: It gave me some points but the problem is not solved yet..
I still get -1 when I call getSelectedItemPosition :(

Comment: It is done I simply put a global variable which indicates the selected item and I used onItemClickedListener to update it :)
Thank you @Raghunandan

Comment: have you tried to set the choice mode, for example : listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

Answer (score 9):

I have had same problem (not working `setSelection()` called immediately after `notifyDataSetChanged()`), this finally helped me:

```
    lv.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lv.setSelection(mSelectedPosition);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came to this question where listView.setSelection(int position) didn't seem to work one thing that worked for me was to make sure to have this code run after I was done updating my listView adapter. If you try to do this before that is done then the scroll position will be totally not at the desired spot once the listView is done updating.

In extreme cases you may need to put in a runnable like MiroM found but this is often not necessary. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
                listView.clearFocus();
                listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                listView.setSelection(focusPosOnline);
    }
});
```

Above Worked For Me